# Configure ESLint RuleTester to use Typescript Parser

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

I am trying to write some custom ESLint rules for my typescript based project. In my project I am using eslint/typescript for linting.

I have already written a custom eslint plugin which validates a custom rule. Now I want to write the unit tests for that custom rule. My test file looks like this:

```html
/**
 * @fileoverview This rule verifies that logic can only depend on other logic
 * @author Dayem Siddiqui
 */
"use strict";

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Requirements
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const typescriptParser = require('@typescript-eslint/parser')
var rule = require("../../../lib/rules/logic-dependency"),
  RuleTester = require("eslint").RuleTester;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Tests
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
typescriptParser.parseForESLint()
var ruleTester = new RuleTester({ parserOptions: {} });
ruleTester.run("logic-dependency", rule, {
  valid: [
    `class DeleteLogic {

        }
    class CreateLogic {
            constructor(private deleteLogic: DeleteLogic) {}
    }`
  ],

  invalid: [
    {
      code: `class ExternalClient {

            }
            
            class UpdateLogic {
                constructor(private externalClient: ExternalClient) {}
            }`,
      errors: [
        {
          message: "Logic cannot have a dependency on client",
          type: "MethodDefinition"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

Right now my tests a failing because by default eslint only understand plain Javascript code. I understand that I need to somehow configure it to use a custom parser that allows it to understand/parse typescript code. However I am unable to find a good example online on how to do that

Answer (score 10):

The RuleTester constructor takes eslint's  [parser options](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options) that allow for configuring the [parser itself](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser). So pass it in like this and Bob's your uncle:

```js
const ruleTester = new RuleTester({
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
});
```

typescript-eslint's own rule tests (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/tests/rules/adjacent-overload-signatures.test.ts)) use exactly this.

(Was searching for an answer to this question and kept up ending here, so I posted the solution I found here in the hope it'll be useful.)

---

**eslint 6.0+**

Incorporating [@Sonata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498238/sonata)'s comment:

Eslint 6.0+ requires an absolute path to the parser (see [6.0 migration guide](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/migrating-to-6.0.0.md#rule-tester-parser)):

```js
const ruleTester = new RuleTester({
  parser: require.resolve('@typescript-eslint/parser'),
});
```

Comment: New versions of eslint (>v6.0.0) requires you to use an absolute path: `parser: require.resolve('@typescript-eslint/parser')`. See https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/migrating-to-6.0.0.md#rule-tester-parser

Answer (score 0):

Use a package such as the [typescript-eslint/parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/parser). I can't provide much more than a link in this case. If you need help using it, let me know.

Comment: Other than writing an entirely new parser, there is no other option.